# Serving multiple result Futures as soon as available to a client

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.2, future

I have a page that is populated by data that I get using different calls to distant servers. Some requests take longer than others, the way I do things now is that I do all the calls at once and wrap the whole thing in a `Future`, then put the the whole thing in a `Action.async` for Play to handle.

This, theoretically, does the job but I don't want my users to be waiting a long time and instead start loading the page part by part. Meaning that as soon as data is available for a given request to a distant server, it should be sent to the client as Json or whatever.

I was able to partially achieve this using EventSource by modifying Play's event-source sample by doing something like this:

```
Ok.chunked((enumerator1  &> EventSource()) >- (enumerator2  &> EventSource())).as("text/event-stream")
```

and the enumerators as follows:

```
val enumerator1: Enumerator[String] = Enumerator.generateM{
   Future[Option[String]]{Thread.sleep(1500); Some("Hello")}
}

val enumerator2: Enumerator[String] = Enumerator.generateM{
   Future[Option[String]]{Thread.sleep(2000); Some("World!")}
}
```

As you probably have guessed, I was expecting to have "Hello" after 1.5s and then "World!" 0.5s later sent to the client, but I ended up receiving "Hello" every 1.5s and "World!" every 2s.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to stop sending an information once it has been correctly delivered to the client using the method above?
2. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `generateM`, it's for building enumerators that can return multiple values. `generateM` takes a function that either returns a `Some`, to produce the next value for the `Enumerator`, or `None`, to signal that the `Enumerator` is complete. Because your function always returns `Some`, you create `Enumerator`s that are infinite in length.

You just want to convert a `Future` into an `Enumerator`, to create an `Enumerator` with a single element:

```
Enumerator.flatten(future.map(Enumerator(_)))
```

Also, you can interleave your enumerators and then feed the result into `EventSource()`. Parenthesis are unnecessary as well (methods that start with `>` have precedence over methods with `&`).

```
enumerator1  >- enumerator2 &> EventSource()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this tonight. Although, I suspect that this will have the same behavior as what I tried before: Having the results of these enumerators sent indefinitely.

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify why that won't happen. Also an edit to the code, it needed an `(_)`.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand better now. I will let you know about the outcome as soon as I try this solution.

Comment: I ended up using Comet with the iframe method.